# Loading spinner is not showing while doing a HTTP request in Angular

Tags: angular

I'm doing a web application in Angular 8 and I want to show a loading spinner while doing a HTTP request.

The loading spinner is not showing with my implementation and I could not find the reason.

Service

```
@Injectable()
export class UserService {

  // Caching
  private bsResource: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject([]);
  private readonly resources$: Observable<string[]> = this.bsResource.asObservable();

  constructor(
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {
  }

  // Calling this method the loading spinner is not showing.
  getResources(): Observable<string[]> {
    if (this.bsResource.getValue().length === 0) {
      this.fetchResourceList().toPromise().then(res => this.bsResource.next(res));
    }

    return this.resources$;
  }

  // The loading spinner appears if I use this method directly and make this method public.
  private fetchResourceList(): Observable<string[]> {
    return this.http.get<string[]>('MY_URL');
  }
}
```

Component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './create-new.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./create-new.component.scss']
})
export class CreateNewComponent {
  resourceList$: Observable<string[]> = this.service.getResources();

  constructor(
    private service: UserService
  ) { }
}
```

Template

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="resourceSelect">* Resources</label>
  <div *ngIf="resourceList$ | async as resourceList; else loading">
     <ng-container *ngIf="resourceList.length; else noResults" >
        <div *ngFor="let r of resourceList; index as i">
          <!-- Show the result using checkboxes -->
        </div>
     </ng-container>
  </div>
</div>

<ng-template #loading>
  <br/>
  <div class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm text-muted" role="status">
    <span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #noResults>
  <div class="text-muted">No results.</div>
</ng-template>
```

I don't understand why by using `this.service.getResources()` the loading spinner is not showing and if I use `this.service.fetchResourceList()` the loading spinner appears correctly.

My goal is to show the loading spinner correctly using the example that I have provided and keeping the method that I'm calling in my component.

Comment: Your code looks so complicated for such a simple call... Did you clean your code before posting it, or is it the full code ?

Comment: @Random Hi, I have deleted a lot of things that is not important for my question. I have cleaned it before posting it, that is the exact code that I use today. It seems large because I'm implementing a local cache to save the information in memory to avoid unnecessary HTTP requests in the future. At least that is how I see it.

Comment: Do you see any errors in console? Can you also confirm if the http call is made successfully?

Comment: @KarthickManoharan Hi, there is no errors in console and I can confirm that the HTTP call is made correctly. The information/result from the request is showing, but the loading spinner doesn't.

Comment: Thanks for confirming. Can you also make sure by delaying the response time by throttling the speed? Because if the API is fast to respond then the spinner might not be displayed

Comment: are you using HttpService in many places? is it possible for you switch to HttpClient instead?

Comment: I think the problem is you have to use `.asObservable()` when you return a `BehaviorSubject`

Comment: @KarthickManoharan I have delayed the response time and the loading spinner is not showing yet.

Comment: @Radik That extension don't have a meaning for my goal/question, I forgot to remove it, I will remove it from my example to avoid confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spent time to reproduce it in a sandbox, but finally found that the problem comes from the initialization of your `BehaviorSubject`. The first value of `bsResource` is `[]`. So in your `*ngIf`, when the pipe `async` subscribes to it, it receives the value `[]`, which is truthy, so the `*ngIf` is instantly true, and never triggers the else (loading) block.

All you have to do is to initialize your `BehaviorSubject` with a null value (and then fix the code using it, to be null-safe):

```
private bsResource: BehaviorSubject<string[]> = new BehaviorSubject(null);
```

And when you use it:

```
const cachedValue = this.bsResource.getValue();
if (!cachedValue || cachedValue.length === 0) {
  this.fetchResourceList().subscribe(res => this.bsResource.next(res));
}
```

I'm saying it again, you should not use `Promises`, use `.subscribe`, which works the same as `toPromise().then`. You should NEVER use Promise. `.toPromise` is only usefull when you are upgrading Angular, where most of the code uses `Promises`, and don't want to upgrade the whole code at once.

Comment: You said that I need to initialize BehaviorSubject with `null` but, then you add it initialized with `[]`, I'm confused now. Another thing is that I think there is a logic issue inside of your `if` statement, since the default value is `null` then, is impossible to enter that statement. If that will be the first time that the application is run, then, it will never enter to that statement because it's obviously `null` and obviously is not `length === 0`. Also, if we are subscribing we should unsubscribe after saving the result, I'm wrong? Is not good to keep the subscription open.

Comment: @RRGT19 indeed, I copy-pasted a bit too quickly. Fixed the 2 lines of code :) Also, yes you have to unsubscribe (with a `takeUnit`, or an attribute saving the subscription)

Comment: If we are subscribing we should unsubscribe after saving the result, I'm wrong? Is not good to keep the subscription open. I can unsubscribe after saving the result? I don't know what's the correct thing to do in this case.

Comment: Yes you can. Naturally, I would prefere completing the BehaviorSubject, or use `take(1)` or something like this, but it is not that simple, have to check if it would work... The easiest/safest way is indeed to unsubscribe inside the subscribe. But beware, you will first receive a `null`, and then the actual value. So you may add a `filter` pipe before the subscribe, or add an `if` inside the subscribe.

Comment: Yeah, `.toObservable().pipe( filter(r => r !== null), take(1) )` would do the trick, I guess

Comment: I know that the first value of the BehaviorSubject will be `null`, but, just to confirm, after we do `this.bsResource.next(res)` inside of the subscription, it's safe to unsubscribe after?

Comment: when the component receives a *real* value, yes you can unsubscribe. But you have to unsubscribe in the component, not the service.

Comment: Understood. But I have in my mind that the line `this.fetchResourceList().subscribe(res => this.bsResource.next(res));` since it's in the service, the subscription will exists in the service and it will be open, I don't have a way to unsubscribe from this from the component. Unless I do something like `const subs = this.fetchResourceList().subs...` and inside after saving the value do `subs.unsubscribe();`. I can not finish this subscription in the component. I don't know if you get my point.

Comment: You don't have to unsubscribe from `this.fetchResourceList().subscribe`, since `this.fetchResourceList()` is not a `Subject`, it is an `Observable` which is completed when the server responds. You never have to unsubscribe from HTTP call.